# Using traffic manager to loadbalance internal azure resources(storage, service bus, etc)?

Tags: azure, high-availability

Is it possible to use traffic manager to manage the connection to internal azure services(storage, service bus etc).

the goal is to have multiple storage accounts and queue's so that if one fail's the other application can still work.

I know that it is possible to build my application so it does this automatically. but can i use traffic manager to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i use traffic manager to achive this?

No, we can't work traffic manager in this way.

Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, it uses DNS responses to direct end-user traffic to globally distributed endpoints. Clients then connect to those endpoints directly. And **traffic manager only supports Internet-facing applications.**
More information about traffic manager, refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview).

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE (6/22/2017)

## As the services will probably need your "tenant" suffix mytenant.servicebus.windows.net in order to work, you will probably not be able to use it with Traffic manager and also the SAS tokens are specific to the namespace.

Traffic Manager needs only an endpoint that can reply a GET request with Status Code 200 OK in order to be able to probe the endpoint successfully.
Your service bus can respond a GET request with 200 OK successfully on the root path on HTTP/HTTPS.

You can test it with Azure PowerShell and wget

PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://<yourservicebusname>.servicebus.windows.net' -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object StatusCode,StatusDescription
```

Wget:

```
wget -S https://<yourservicebusname>.servicebus.windows.net
```

Here you can check how to configure your endpoint with traffic manager.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790439/why-cant-azure-traffic-manager-be-used-with-service-bus

But as explained by Jason We, keep in mind that Traffic Manager works just on DNS level.

It was just released a new feature on Traffic Manager that uses TCP probing instead of HTTP(s) so you can also use it to configure your Service Bus/Storage endpoints.

You can use this PowerShell command below to test if the TCP probe succeeds

```
tnc <storageaccountname>.queue.core.windows.net -Port 80
tnc <storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net -Port 80
tnc <storageaccountname>.file.core.windows.net -Port 80
tnc <storageaccountname>.table.core.windows.net -Port 80
```

On Linux:

```
nc -zv <storageaccountname>.queue.core.windows.net 80
```

Here you can find more info about the TCP probe configurations: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/aztmfftcp/